# Django | Dynamic textfield show depends on selected checkbox

Tags: jquery, django, checkbox, input, show

I want to show specific textfield next to checkbox, but my id's and values of the checkbox is dynamic from table fields. If I click checkbox "id" I want to show "id" textfield.

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19rEg.png)

My template

```
<legend>Choose columns to show:</legend>
            {% for dict in content %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                    {% for key, value in dict.items %}
                        <div style="float:left">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ key }}" name="column" value="{{ key }}"/>
                            <label  for="{{ key }}">{{ key }}</label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-left:200px">
                            <span class="show_text">
                                <input type="text" name="contains" placeholder="{{ key }}"/>
                                <br/>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

My JS

```
$(function () {
            $('input[name="contains"]').hide();


            $('input[name="column"]').on('click', function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    //alert($(this).val())
                    $('input[name="contains"]').fadeIn()
                } else {
                    $('input[name="contains"]').fadeOut()
                }
             })
            })
```

My code showing all of the textfields, but I don't know how to show specific one.